# Problema con Insert en Python, los números del string no se arreglan en el orden que deberían

Tags: python, insert

estoy intentando hacer un código que recibe un string con números en orden aleatorio y los ordena, sin embargo no funciona, aquí el código:

```
sentence="4 2 1 3 6 5"
oNumbers=[]

for i in sentence:
    if i in ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"]:
        oNumbers.insert(int(i)-1, i)
    else:
        pass

print(oNumbers)
```

Y este es el resultado:

```
['1', '4', '3', '2', '5', '6']
```

Comment: Mira cómo va añadiendo los elementos uno a uno haciendo el print(oNumbers) dentro del for. No está haciendo lo que esperas, no es que las posiciones 0,1,2 queden vacías y ponga el cuatro donde corresponde. Tu estrategia para buscar la posición de cada elemento debe ser diferente. Y ya que estamos, ¿puedes usar `sort`?

Comment: Cual crees que es la longitud de la lista `oNumbers` en cada iteracion?

Answer (score 1):

El método `list.insert(pos,valor)` **no** crea los elementos intermedios para que `valor` quede realmente en la posición requerida. Ejemplo

```
a=[]
a.insert(4,'X')
a
Out[39]: ['X']
```

El nuevo elemento quedo insertado en la primera posición, pues el método no crea los elementos para llenar las posiciones 0, 1, 2, y 3 previas.

Probemos insertando otro elemento:

```
a.insert(2,'Y')
a
Out[41]: ['X', 'Y']
```

Como ves, tampoco quedo en la posición 2 donde se pidio.

Sigamos con el ejemplo:

```
a.insert(1, 'Z')
a
Out[43]: ['X', 'Z', 'Y']
```

Ahora si `Z` quedó en la posición 1, pues todas las posiciones anteriores ya estaban llenas.

**Analisis**

```
sentence="4 2 1 3 6 5"

for i in sentence:
    if i in ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"]:
        oNumbers.insert(int(i)-1, i)
```

En la primera iteración con `i="4"`, se insertara la cadena "4" en la posición `int(i)-1 = 3`, lo que no es cierto. Como la lista está vacía, el "4" quedara en la posición cero. Y de ahí para adelante, repeticiones de lo mismo.

**Solución**

Este es un burdo método de ordenamiento por inserción. La idea es tener un arreglo, tabla o lista donde la posición i-esima almacene el valor `i`. Si el valor `i` no viene en los datos de entrada, en esa posición se deja un `None`.

Para recorrer `sentence` aplico `split`, que me retorna una lista con los valores, que pueden ser de cualquier tamaño. Teniendo la lista, puedo aplicar `max`. Con el valor máximo puedo dimensionar e inicializar apropiadamente `oNumbers`, usando `None` en cada posición para indicar que no hay un valor ahí.

```
oNumbers= [None] * (1 + max(valores))
```

Con eso, solo falta recorrer `valores` actualizando `oNumbers`.

```
sentence="4 2 1 3 6 5"
valores = [int(x) for x in sentence.split()]
oNumbers= [False] * (1 + max(valores))

for valor in valores:
     oNumbers[valor] = valor

print([val for val in oNumbers if val])
```

produce:

```
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
```

Nota: la solución es un poco verbosa en aras de la claridad.

Answer (score 0):

Siguiendo el comentario, si la cosa es ordenar:

```
sentence="4 2 7 3 6 5 1"
oNumbers=[]

for i in sentence:
    if i in ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"]:
        oNumbers.insert(int(i), i)
        print(oNumbers)
        
    else:
        pass

oNumbers.sort()
print(oNumbers)
```

El método [sort](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) se encarga de todo.

Comment: En ese caso simplemente puedes hacer `list(sentece)`

Comment: Usando `sort` el problema se reduce a `print(list(sentence).sort())`.

Answer (score 0):

Simplificando código con ayuda de una compresión de lista se puede hacer en 1 linea.

```py
sentence="4 2 1 3 6 5"
oNumbers=sorted([i for i in sentence if i !=" "])

print(oNumbers)
```

la compresión de lista es un ciclo `for` *abreviado* el cual dice que itere en la variable `sentece` y que añada el carácter si es diferente de vacío y luego aplicamos la función `sorted()` que sirve para ordenar, es lo mismo que hacer.

```py
sentence="4 2 1 3 6 5"
oNumbers=[i for i in sentence if i !=" "]

oNumbers.sort() #metodo sort()

print(oNumbers)
```